# VBScript error 'invalid routine call or argument' when trying to escape quotes

Tags: vbscript, escaping, quotes

I'm trying to create a shortcut that points to a batch file with some arguments in VBScript and I am getting the error that's in the title.

I tried to escape by putting """string""" or """""string""""" but I am getting the same error

```vb
SET fso = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.lnk"
If fso.FileExists(shFile) Then
fso.DeleteFile(shFile)
End If
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(shFile)
oLink.TargetPath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\test\test.bat"" ""argument1"""
oLink.Save
```

I'm expecting the script to create a shortcut with quoted arguments, but I'm only getting the error that's in the title

Comment: You should get rid of the quotes between bat and argument1. Edit: why do you have the argument1 in your path?

Comment: Because I need to pass an argument to the script.

Comment: Oh, I solved by myself, you have to use oLink.Arguments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved by myself, you just have to use `oLink.Arguments`